# How to import a certificate into Azure KeyVault with key size of 1024 bits?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault

Trying to import certificate (with 1024 Bits key size) into Azure KeyVault using Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate command. Getting errors :

> Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.ImportAzureKeyVaultCertificate
>
> Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : **Unsupported key size (1024)**.
>   Supported sizes are [2048, 3072, 4096]

How to overcome this limitation when it is a requirement of application to use 1024 bits for key size?

Comment: My guess, in short, would be to not use KeyVault. Apparently your key is too small. So you can either use a larger key, or use a different way to store your certificate.

Comment: Depending on your apps requirements, you might be able to store it in a secret instead of a cert...  Base64 encode if necessary, etc.

Comment: @bmoore-msft thank's for suggestion, do you think there would be benefit to have certificate itself password protected, or it would be redundant?

Comment: I think it depends if you think that cert will be used/stored/exposed outside of Azure...  e.g. if it's on a VM at some point, then the extra security won't hurt - but inside of KeyVault itself, the PW doesn't add much.